# Reconfiguring deployment script for Windows

Tags: node.js, windows

Trying to set up a quick deployment environment on my windows computer only pulling the git repo. I'm blocked from deployment with the line:

"deploy": "cd ../frontend && npm run build && cd ../backend && **cp -R **../frontend/dist . && gcloud config configurations activate visualization && gcloud app deploy"

What is the windows equivalent?

modified cp to copy, put pathnames in quotes

Answer (score 0):

Changed from:

```
&& cp -R ../frontend/dist . &&
```

to:

```
&& copy ..\\frontend\\dist &&
```